# Access separate docroot in apache

Tags: php, apache

I have a site on a server running Apache2 that resides at docroot /var/www/html.  I want to access some of the files on a separate site at docroot /var/www/vhosts/othersite.  Is there a way to access these files from the first site?

Thanks,
Chris Birk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is with mod_rewrite, and there are several ways of mapping URLs to different paths [in the documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

The cheatin' way of doing it would be to create a symbolic link from the directory outside the document root to a directory inside the document root, making sure the user Apache runs has can read that directory, and follow symlinks is turned on.

Yet another way of doing it would be to create a subdomain as a VirtualHost, with a document root of that other directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can include them using the include and require calls, or use symlinks to create a soft link in project 1 from project 2. These obviously depend on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Edit: Oh, also, you could potentially add the folders you want to PATH.